# add background image and push it to the back scene

Tags: image, background

A simple question. I have already finished my app with full functionality and I now need to add background images to make it look nicer. However, if I simply add on top of each view an image view, the image appears in the foreground, covering the buttons/textfields etc. How do I get round this?

Also, one of the views of my app is a scroll view. Should this be treated differently concerning background images?

Thanks

Comment: you mean you want to add fixed background for each activity in your app ?

Comment: yes. My app has a main view with 4 buttons and 4 corresponding (sub)views to which the user can navigate. I would like to add different fixed background images to each (sub)view. One of the subviews is a scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I found the (very simple one-click) solution: editor>arrange>send to back...